# How to get rid of deformations of poles caused by sub division?

Tags: modeling

How can I get rid of the weird poles artifacts seen at the nose?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In short, don't use n-gons or tris.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47934/forcing-subdivide-to-create-non-zig-zag-edges/47938#47938

Comment: always end your cap's like this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29086/7777 and you will be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method greatly reduces the impact the poles.

1. Add a knife cut close to the front of the nose.

   (enable *cut through* <kbd>z</kbd> and *angle constraint* <kbd>c</kbd>)

[image]

---

**Final Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your instance here is the workflow, Ill circle back later and give the text step-by-step run down. By the way this does not eliminate, but practically It does visually. You can, but you need to get rid of that Apex, and figure out how to re-topo at this location. However, this is a good first start.

[image]

Comment: To cut on both sides at a time with **Knife** tool while cutting enable *Cut through* option.