# How to get rid of subsurface shading artefacts

Tags: modifiers, objects

I notice this radial striping often when I use the subsurface modifier on shapes with curved segments. How can I prevent it or remove it?

[image]

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47934/forcing-subdivide-to-create-non-zig-zag-edges/47938#47938

Comment: @cegaton I tried the accepted solution, and while it helps, it's just reducing the problem, not eliminating it. So i tried extruding the inner edge loop without moving it, like you suggested, and that worked. But in this figure, that made that edge loop really sharp, which isn't what i wanted. So, i scaled it inwards. Then it looked great. I'm not sure what to take from this - subsurf has trouble with angles on the edge of a large n-gon?

Comment: @kimholder - cegaton's link is still pretty related, although I would say that you could select the big n-gon in face selection mode, and use the "i" key to do some inset operations on the face. The problem really comes down to a big flat face trying to smooth out to a whole bunch of vertices. When that happens you are going to see the rippled influence.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how the subsurf modifier will subdivide an ngon (a polygon or face made of more than 4 vertices)

The rest of your object is made of quads and subdivides nicely and regularly with the subsurf modifier, whereas the ngon creates a subset of polygons arranged in a way that will create the artifacts you are experiencing.

[image: ![enter image description here]

There are a few solutions:

add a number of subdivisions or loop cuts to make the ngon smaller and the issues less evident:

[image]

You can delete the ngon and fill the surface with quads using the grid fill tool (this requires that you have an even number of vertices on the loop ring)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the huge ngon on the top. Try filling it with a grid-like patch of mesh.

Check out this [topology guide](http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/) especially the part about Cylinder Caps